# Virtual mapping of kernel and module pages

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I'm using `VMAP` function to create memory writable mapping as it suggested in [ksplice](https://github.com/jirislaby/ksplice)  project. Here is the implementation of [map_writable](https://github.com/jirislaby/ksplice/blob/master/kmodsrc/ksplice.c#L1187) function:

```
/*
 * map_writable creates a shadow page mapping of the range
 * [addr, addr + len) so that we can write to code mapped read-only.
 *
 * It is similar to a generalized version of x86's text_poke.  But
 * because one cannot use vmalloc/vfree() inside stop_machine, we use
 * map_writable to map the pages before stop_machine, then use the
 * mapping inside stop_machine, and unmap the pages afterwards.
 */
static void *map_writable(void *addr, size_t len)
{
        void *vaddr;
        int nr_pages = DIV_ROUND_UP(offset_in_page(addr) + len, PAGE_SIZE);
        struct page **pages = kmalloc(nr_pages * sizeof(*pages), GFP_KERNEL);
        void *page_addr = (void *)((unsigned long)addr & PAGE_MASK);
        int i;

        if (pages == NULL)
                return NULL;

        for (i = 0; i < nr_pages; i++) {
                if (__module_address((unsigned long)page_addr) == NULL) {
                        pages[i] = virt_to_page(page_addr);
                        WARN_ON(!PageReserved(pages[i]));
                } else {
                        pages[i] = vmalloc_to_page(page_addr);
                }
                if (pages[i] == NULL) {
                        kfree(pages);
                        return NULL;
                }
                page_addr += PAGE_SIZE;
        }
        vaddr = vmap(pages, nr_pages, VM_MAP, PAGE_KERNEL);
        kfree(pages);
        if (vaddr == NULL)
                return NULL;
        return vaddr + offset_in_page(addr);
}
```

This function works well when I used it to map kernel's text addresses. All fine and I can rewrite read-only data well via the mapping.

Now, I need to modify kernel module's text. Given the symbol address inside the module, I use the same method. The mapping I've got seems to be valid. But all my changes visible only in that mapping and not in the module!

I suppose that in case of module mapping I get something like copy-on-write but I can't prove it.

Can anyone explain me what's happend and why I can use it for mapping kernel and can't for modules?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a `map_writable` problem as I have a bug in my code. All works fine, closed.

Comment: You could accept your answer and remove the "All works fine, closed" portion from it.  The question itself is okay.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question and will be deleted. You probably have something useful to say with your bug fix, and unless it is a trash mistake you should show the real solution. You can delete your own question, but you should do so only if you are certain that your fix can never be useful to anyone.